# Cómo eliminar margenes (margin) o rellenos (padding) del sitio web

Tags: html

[image: foto explicativa]

Hago un formulario para mis alumnos y en mi título quisiera que el color abarcara todo en los laterales y no quedara esos espacios. Pego el pedacito de código:

```html
<div class="container-fluid form2">

  <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>

    <div style="background-color: #EBC742;" class="text-center p-3">
      <h1>Formulario Estudiantes EPO47</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Veo que está usando bootstrap, puede integrar la propiedad `p-0` en la clase del contenedor. Otra opción sería quitar solo los márgenes laterales con `pl-0 pr-0`, me avisa si le funcionó

Comment: Si revisas con el inspector vas a darte cuenta que ninguno de los elementos que muestras tiene ni margen ni `padding`, pero el cuerpo (`body`) si. Si realmente deseas que ocupe de lado a lado de la página debes modificar el estilo del cuerpo (`body`) configurando margen 0.

Comment: También puedes aplicar el estilo `margin: 0` para el `<body>` o el contenedor.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev puse eso en el contenedor principal y de hecho la cabezera del titulo se desporbda un poco pero aparte tambien quita el padding del formulario osea se pega todo y se desborda un poco quisier amentener el padding del formulario y que el contenedor donde esta la cabezera del formulario abarque todo pero sin desbordarse

Comment: @HeytalePazguato le puse  body{ background-color: #d4d4d4; margin: 0;} pero nada paso.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev  puse el margin en 0 como sugeriste pero lo que sucede es que todo el contenedor se tira a la izquierda

Comment: Utiliza `margin-left: 0 !important;` y `margin-right: 0 !important;`, me dices si te funciona.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev  igual solo tira el contendedor a la izquierda , claro si quito el marginleft lo tira a la derecha

Comment: Podrías pasar el código completo en un [proyecto](https://codepen.io/pen/) y compartirlo? para ver mejor el problema.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev  https://codepen.io/marcolost/pen/RwMBOXR  aqui esta

Comment: No sería lo ideal pero con `margin:-4px` en el `<body>` me funcionó.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev gracias cris por tu tiempo